# How to setup a form for Majordomo list subscription

Tags: forms, email, lists

I am currently in the process of setting up a simple website for a small community. One of the requests is to have a mailing list that is easy to sign up for on the website. The hosting provider provides a mailing system based on Majordomo. Without going into detail, subscribing to Majordomo lists is very simple, as you simply have to send an email with the plain text content

```
subscribe [list] [email-adress]
subscribe [list2] [email-adress]
...
```

to a specific address.

I have tried both `WPForms` as well as `Contact Form 7` to set up a simple form where the user has to enter their email and choose the email lists from a multiple-choice selection. However, the output from the multiple-choice selection should be looped through to create separate lines as in the example above. I have yet to find a way to do this with the form creators I have tried.

So I'm looking for either one of two answers;

1. Is there a form addon that is flexible enough to define a loop to write subscriptions to separate lines?
2. Is there a proper WP addon that can handle Majordomo subscriptions?
3. Is there a completely different way to do this that I've missed? Injecting custom code in the form creators?